# What are "zsh" commands for cut/copy/paste?

Tags: terminal, zsh, configuration, oh-my-zsh, xbindkeys

I want to configure `zsh` and bind its cutting, copying and pasting commands (or maybe they're called widgets idk) to different escape sequences, the ones that my terminal program sends across. Problem is that I don't know what the `cut`, `copy` and `paste` commands are in `zsh`.

I searched and read `man zshzle` but to no avail. Does anyone know ?

---

This is basically what I'm trying to do in my `.zshrc`:

```
bindkey '^[x' cut
bindkey '^[c' copy
bindkey '^[v' paste
```

but don't know what the actual correct `cut`, `copy`, `paste` commands are...

Comment: You're wanting to do copy with `Ctrl+C` in the terminal, instead of sending an interrupt signal to the foreground process (like it usually does)?

Answer (score 2):

(Yes, you are correct that keyboard commands are called "widgets" in Zsh.)

If you are using [Zsh's `emacs` keymap](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Keymaps) (which you probably are, since it's the default), then `cut`, `copy` & `paste` are called `kill`, `copy` and `yank` (as they are in [Emacs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs)).

However, although there is exactly

- one [`yank` widget](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-yank),
- [one widget that does `copy` on selected text](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-copy_002dregion_002das_002dkill) and
- [one widget that does `kill` on selected text](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-kill_002dregion),

the latter two are actually not commonly used. This is because selecting text in a terminal is generally a pain in the ass. (It involves using the [`set-mark` widget](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-set_002dmark_002dcommand).)

Instead, there are [many widgets that `kill` various parts of the command line](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Modifying-Text), without having to select any text. It's much faster to use these and if you use them successively, without other key presses in between, the killed text is concatenated. For example, if you `backward-kill-word` three times in a row and then later you `yank`, you will get all three words back at once, in the same order in which they originally appeared.

Note, though, that instead of defining new key bindings for yourself, you are probably better off in the long run by learning and getting used to Zsh's default `emacs` key bindings for the various `kill` widgets, as these same or similar keyboard shortcuts are commonly used in many Unix shells and shell programs.

Finally, two more tips about `kill` and `yank`:

- Just like Emacs, Zsh actually has multiple clipboards. As in Emacs, these are collectively called the "kill ring". If you have used `kill` multiple times in the same session on separate occasions (so, not at once in a row), then after you press `yank`, you can press `yank-pop` to cycle between the different kills in your kill ring.
- It's hard to keep track of what's in your kill ring off the top of your head. That's why I wrote a [plugin called `zsh-edit`, which automatically shows you what's in your kill ring](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-edit). Try it! It makes all of this much easier.